# Geb tests often fails with WaitTimeoutException: condition did not pass in 99.0 seconds

Tags: user-interface, selenium, groovy, automated-tests, geb

We have some unstable test at our application which sometimes passes successfully, sometimes fails with `WaitTimeoutException` during a page load.
I've found we're using methods like `waitFor(time)` and `sleep(time)`.
What is the difference between them and which one is better to use? Or there are some better solutions to this problem?

Comment: There may be other errors if your pages take longer than 99 seconds. Might be helpful to post any exceptions. And I can update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Waiting in geb is required for many scenarios. Waiting for a page to load is best done when using the Page pattern where you can define an at checker in your Page e.g:

static at = { waitFor { $('form').@id == "loginForm" } }

When this is used geb will wait until the at checker can verify the page has loaded. Waiting until the set timeout in geb config. This highlights how it works. On any script you can use your own waitFor calls with any condition. The links I provided will show you how this works. In later versions of the geb you can set each at call to explicitly wrap in a waitFor.

```
static at = { $('form').@id == "loginForm" }
```

Also to respond to your question: Sleep should only be used as a last resort as the whole thread sleeps and can disregrad your wait settings. You lose a sense of control of loading and waiting on your scripts when you do this. If you cannot configure the tests to work using waitFor closures with a condition to wait for then maybe you should look at making the pages faster. We use 60 seconds only because of environment problems.

WaitFor(time) is a bit redundant in my opinion, unless you are actually testing time itself.

In geb it is best to work against the page contents rather than using condition that may be out of your control.

[Geb Waiting manual](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#waiting-configuration)

Geb config:

```
    waiting {
        timeout = 30
        retryInterval = 1.0
    }
```

Ajax: Waiting for ajax calls to finish. It will sleep to begin with as most calls are finished in this time then it will check for active ajax calls and sleep some more if its done to give pages time to render. Some dynamic page changes take longer than other so this after sleep can be modified to suit your site or removed completely.

```
    /**
     * Wait for all AJAX requests to finish.
     */
    void waitForAjax(time=350) {
        sleep(time)
        if (!js.exec("return $.active > 0;")) {
            sleep(time) // You may require more wait time here depending on action
            return
        }

        waitForAjax(time)
    }
```

Comment: Your link to the Config page on waiting no longer works.  Try this one http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#waiting-configuration.